# How to use variables set in instance methods that are not called?

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, instance

I am trying to create a pipeline to process some data in Python using a `Class` instead of `functions`. So far my Class has 5 methods (functions) that each process the data a bit further. Now what I really want is to initalise my `Class` and use one `do_all()` method to run through the entire pipeline.

For this I would need to use variabels that are set in `method A` as input for `method B`. To illustrate with some dummy data:

```
Class foo():

    # class variables:
    self.path = '\foo'


    def __init__(self, age):
       self.age = age

    def methodA(meters):
       self.centimeters = meter/100
       return self.centimeters

    def methodB(centimeters=None):
        centimeters = self.centimeters if centimeters is None else centimeters
        self.millimeters = centimeters/100
        return self.millimeters
```

All is well if I instantiate `methodA` and then run `methodB`, because `self.centimeters` is 'created' when running `methodA`.

```
dummy = foo()
cm = dummy.methodA(5)
mm = dummy.methodB()
```

But if I want to run `methodB` from the start it returns an error.

```
dummy = foo()

mm = dummy.methodB()
AttributeError: 'foo' object has no attribute 'centimeters'
```

Now I understand that I need to run `methodA` before, so the `self.centimeters` exists within the class. But I want to know if there is another way.

What I want is: `input data` > `several processes (methodA + methodB)` > `output data`. I also want to be able to run each process `methodA` or `methodB` seperately.

What are my solutions? Should I just run all of the methods in a final method `do_all()`? In a functional paradigm I would create several functions `functionA`, `functionB` etc and just include `functionA` in `functionB` Is that the way to go in a `Class` as well?

Comment: You could use `centimeters if centimeters is not None else getattr(self, 'centimeters', 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Some strange logic here in your methodB: if you passed nonzero value to centimeters, method ignores it and uses existing self.centimeters (which can not exist at the moment of calling methodB), and if you pass None, you use passed value (i.e. None). Maybe first line in your method should be like this?

```
centimeters = centimeters if centimeters else self.centimeters
```

Or you can just initiate self.centimeters directly in **init**

Comment: if ```methodB()``` is called use ```self.centimeters```, if ```methodB(20)``` is called, use ```20```. That is what I am going for there

Comment: that's exactly what I've supposed. You can do it even easier:
centimeters = centimeters or self.centimeters